# Import excel, progress bar during my logic

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, import-from-excel, maatwebsite-excel

I'm using maatwebsite/excel: ~2.1.0, to import and excel to my aplication.
I save the file in my server, after that I

```
Excel::filter('chunk')
    ->selectSheetsByIndex(0)
    ->load($target_file)
    ->chunk(100, function($rows) {               
        foreach($rows as $row ){
            //al my logic
        }
    }
```

I would like to print a progress bar in the browser during this logic. 
I'm don't want to use ajax().

Comment: See this : https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/artisan#writing-output Hope it helps you!

Comment: You can try https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/ or something along those lines.

Comment: If I use jquery-ui progressbar or $ajax() I know that it is posible, I would like to know if is possible to do using laravel directly in the controller, maybe there is a function or I dont know.... I think that the answer is not but here are a lot of clever people that knows laravel all tricks

Comment: Try something like: `$bar = $this->output->createProgressBar(count($users));`

Comment: PROCESS bar or PROGRESS bar? Please verify your title.